# Update Android Studio 4.1.2 to 2020.3.1 failure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I'm trying to update **Android Studio** *4.1.2* to *2020.3.1*, update fails and suggest to read `idea_updater.log`. Here's the dialog box prompted during update:

[image]

The only relevant error I can found is this one:

```
03/08 13:57:57 INFO  DeleteAction.doApply - Delete action. File: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin
03/08 13:57:57 INFO  DeleteAction.doApply - Delete: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin
03/08 13:57:57 ERROR Patch.apply - apply failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot delete: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.tryDelete(Utils.java:115)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.access$000(Utils.java:12)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils$1.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:77)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils$1.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:68)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.delete(Utils.java:68)
    at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.doApply(DeleteAction.java:71)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:213)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$apply$3(Patch.java:406)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:454)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:399)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:116)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:381)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner._main(Runner.java:180)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:41)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin: Impossibile accedere al file. Il file è utilizzato da un altro processo.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:273)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.tryDelete(Utils.java:89)
    ... 15 more
```

it seems that it's unable to remove `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin` folder since it's locked from another process.

At the moment the error dialog appear the folder cited above is empty (before update holds 55 files and 3 folders).

But AFAIK there are not other processes trying to use any resource in **Android Studio** while the update is running.
Tried several times with the same result. Any hints? Should I remove **Android Studio** and try a fresh new install?

Comment: Please try to `Open Task Manager` and look for `OpenJDK Platform Binary` and force-kill it. But, it seems it's not running currently as mentioned by you. Additionally, I would manually delete the folder. Have you been prompted to provide Admin password while updating Android Studio?

Comment: There's nothin with such name....

Comment: Use Sysinternal Process Explorer and use the `Find handle or DLL` function using the path `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin` to find out hich process is blocking the directory and thus the update.

Answer (score 2):

Download a fresh JRE and install it to another folder NOT below your android studio folder

for latest openJDK as of date (my favorite), download it [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html#license-lightbox)

restart windows in safe mode

delete the c:\program files\android\android studio\jre and its subfolders

restart windows to normal mode

run Android studio and pick the fresh JRE folder you've just installed

try the update again

Comment: I bet this should fine but I cannot test this.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to find any lock on such folder. I needed to uninstall 4.1.2 and reinstall 2020.3.1 (everything worked).